# How to open webpage in google sheets sidebar after button click

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

anyone has a solution for how to open simple website in a sidebar inside google sheets **after button click**?

The website i am trying to reach is a HTML form that fills values into the Google sheets based on the tutorial i found here online. 
My test-form URL: http://testovacka.webz.cz/

Currently using HTML form in a popup window and the sidebar looks more practical.

Comment: Have you looked into the HtmlService? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/  I could be wrong, but it would surprise me a lot if Google actually allowed opening external websites from inside Sheets. This could be a massive loophole for stealing user's private data. You should probably either create HTML templates inside the Script Editor or use the Sheets API for your web app instead of having the users interact with the sidebar

Comment: Hi Anton, this is actually exactely what i have been looking for. Thank you very much.